# Where do objects of "java.lang.Class" class reside

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I searched a lot but I couldn't find the answer for where do objects of `java.lang.Class` class reside - is it the Heap or Metaspace/PermGen. My own understanding is that objects of `java.lang.Class` represents the class metadata so they should reside on Metaspace (or PermGen for pre-Java8).

Could someone please confirm, and I need some official documentation which clearly mentions the same.

Comment: 1) It really doesn't matter where they live. 2) At least *some* of the metadata lives in metaspace.  3)  It is not "officially" documented because it is an implementation detail (and it doesn't matter, and you don't *need* the documentation.).  4) If you really want to know, there is the source code ......

Comment: @StephenC Points 1 and 4 aren't helpful.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - I disagree.  It really doesn't matter where they live.  It changes not one iota from a practical programming perspective where the objects live ... or how little / much of the metadata is in the heap vs metaspace.  And it is helpful to help someone to realize this.

Comment: @StephenC I agree with point 1 up to the point that I have to disagree with point 4. The [heap memory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) is a formal term, so it’s irrelevant what the source code does. This is best illustrated by the fact that prior to JDK 8, the HotSpot JVM reported the PermGen as “non heap” memory to monitoring tools, despite it contained objects and was garbage collected, so it had all properties of heap memory. This demonstrates that the implementation is not authoritative to answer this, but also that it really doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, objects of `java.lang.Class` class can't be considered as class metadata. **Class metadata is nothing but JVM's internal representation of Java classes** - basically when JVM loads `.class` file then it doesn't store all the bytecode present in that `.class` file, but creates an internal data structure that holds everything which is needed from that `.class` file and that gets stored in Metaspace or PermGen.

So, based on my knowledge I would say objects of `java.lang.Class` class will reside on heap and class metadata of `java.lang.Class` class will reside on Metaspace or PermGen. However, I can't give any official doc about first part of my statement, and offical doc for second part can be read over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/other-considerations.html#GUID-B29C9153-3530-4C15-9154-E74F44E3DAD9).